# Serialize a List<Filter> for storing ina hidden field in MVC5

Tags: serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

```
[Serializable]
public class ColumnFilter
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string DynamicFilter { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public ColumnFilter() {}

    public ColumnFilter (string fieldName, string fieldType,string  dynamicFilter, object value)
    {
        this.FieldName = fieldName;
        this.DynamicFilter = dynamicFilter;
        this.Value = value;
        this.FieldType =  fieldType;
    }
}
```

I want to serialize a List of ColumnFilter objects so I can store it in a hidden field. The code for hidden field is as below. **How would I serialize this List in a controller action for this situation?**

```
@Html.DropDownList("SearchField", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SearchFields"])
@Html.DropDownList("SearchCondition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SearchConditions"])
@Html.TextBox("SearchText", (string)ViewBag.SearchText)
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="command" class="btn btn-default" />
<input type="submit" value="Show All" name="command" class="btn btn-default" />
@Html.Hidden("ColumnFilters", ViewBag.ColumnFilters)
```

I have a drop-down of columns in corresponding MVC view as shown.

[image: Filtering on multiple columns in MVC]

Comment: Why would you want to send all that extra data and post it back? `ColumnFilter` does not have a parameterless constructor so the collection will be null anyway

Comment: Ok. I will add the empty constructor. I want to maintain the list of filters applied to a grid, so any new filter that  user submits is applied with all previous filters. Else, user can only apply one filter at a time.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but how would "serializing" the list help. If you really need the collection on the client, add hidden inputs for each property in a `for` loop or create an editor template for type `ColumnFilte` (that has hidden inputs for each property) and use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.YourCollection)`

Comment: When user clicks on Search button, I could get all previous filters by de-serializing the hidden field value. There is already C# code in my project to get the filtered list from database given List<ColumnFilter> collection. I can select a column and specify its filter using the operator drop-down and value text box, and then click Search. A screen shot for this is shown in my post.

Comment: So I could select OrderID and submit a filter for it by clicking Search button. I would then get the grid filtered by this filter. Next, I select the ProductID column from leftmost drop-down and specify another filter, and click Search. Now the new filter as well as the first filter on OrderID will get applied to the grid.

Comment: OK, so is `Search` submitting the form - i.e you want to post back the collection of current filters? If so the rendering the hidden inputs in a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` will work

Comment: I posted more detailed code of View being used. Yes Search posts the form. Can you elaborate a bit more your solution in an answer post? Thanks.

Comment: There are 3 elements to a Filter - filter column, filter operator and filter value. I think I would need a separate hidden field for each of these, each time Search button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render the collection of `ColumnFilter` as hidden inputs, use a `for` loop or an `EditorTemplate`. I strongly recommend you use a view model for this and I've based the answer on this

ViewModel

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
  public string SearchField { get; set; }
  public string SearchCondition { get; set; }
  public string SearchText { get; set; }
  public List<ColumnFilter> CurrentFilters { get; set; }
  public SelectList SearchFieldList { get; set; }
  public SelectList SearchConditionList { get; set; }
}
```

In your get method, assign the initial value of these properties including the `SelectList`s

View

```
@model YourAssembly.FilterViewModel
.....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchField, Model.SearchFieldList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchCondition, Model.SearchConditionList)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchText)
....
// render hidden inputs for each current searc filter
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.CurrentFilters.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentFilters[i].FieldName)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentFilters[i].FieldType)
  ... // other properties of SearchFilter
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FilterViewModel model, string command)
{
  ....
```

Model is now populated with users selected values and the collection of current filters.
Note if your returning the view (i.e. `ModelState` is invalid), your need to reassign the `SelectList` properties.

If there a lot of current filters, you are sending a lot of extra data to the client and then posting it all back. For performance it may be better to store the current filters in session. It may also be worth considering using AJAX to post the data and return a partial view of the grid to avoid having to render the whole page all over again